# OSX Bash Script: Zip files in directory, Rename move and delete

Tags: macos, bash

I have the following directory and am having problems selecting the path:

Server HD/Library/FileMaker Server/Data/Backups/Nightly/NightlyBackups/Databases/*

A) How do I correctly Zip all the files in the * directory,

B) Rename the the Zip file, XXXX_XX_XX_Filemaker Nightly.zip

C) Move XXXX_XX_XX_Filemaker Nightly.zip to HD/Library/FileMaker Server/Data/Backups/Nightly/NightlyBackups/Nightly Zipped folder

Thank you,

John

Comment: Right now I'm just starting with getting the path.  zip -r Test.zip /Server HD/Library/FileMaker Server/Data/Backups/NightlyBackups/Databases/*

Comment: Try enclosing the path in quotes. zip -r Test.zip "/Server HD/Library/FileMaker Server/Data/Backups/NightlyBackups/Databases/"

Answer (score 2):

First, `man` is your friend. The `man` command as in *manual* tells you how to use other commands:

```
$ man zip
```

Don't be overwhelmed by the amount of information. The important thing is to see the various command line parameters and some helpful examples. For example, if you want to include all subdirectories, you would need to use the `--recurse-paths` parameter. Compare this to the `--recurse-patterns` parameter.

You look like you're a pretty much of a beginner with shell scripting and using the shell on your Mac. Look at [Take Control of the Mac Command Line with Terminal](http://www.takecontrolbooks.com/command-line). It's a simple straightforward, not-overly-technical, non-programmer introduction to the command line, and into basic shell scripting. It's a great introduction.